# What is causing null pointer exception error for data transfer from Oracle to Bigquery using Apache Nifi?

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I am currently working with Apache Nifi to transfer data from Oracle to Bigquery.

I have successfully transferred multiple tables from Oracle to Bigquery. One table however is showing an error 'Null pointer exception'.

Null pointer exception usually shows if the Oracle record has null value and the Bigquery table schema does not have 'mode' detail in the json.

I have made sure to get mode and verified if the schema has 'mode', it is still showing the error.

I tried to search [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/GetFile-NullPointerException-on-Nifi-1-1-1/td-p/171380) for fix, but I am on the latest version of Apache Nifi (1.10). I have also noticed that the Jobs are not created in Bigquery. Is this problem related to thread? Or is it something else entirely?

Log:

```
020-01-02 19:12:46,022 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-13] o.a.n.p.gcp.bigquery.PutBigQueryBatch PutBigQueryBatch[id=bbdb10dd-3194-17d3-a9ab-4e1fcc71bd96] null: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:890)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Field.<init>(Field.java:199)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Field.<init>(Field.java:35)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.Field$Builder.build(Field.java:193)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryUtils.mapToField(BigQueryUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryUtils.listToFields(BigQueryUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryUtils.schemaFromString(BigQueryUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.gcp.bigquery.PutBigQueryBatch.onTrigger(PutBigQueryBatch.java:288)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Bigquery schema:

```
[{'mode': 'NULLABLE',        #I tried both 'NULLABLE' and 'REQUIRED'
  'name': 'ASPC_CUTOFFHISTORYID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CDOTYPEID',
  'type': 'NUMERIC'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CHANGECOUNT',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CHANGEHISTORYID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'DESCRIPTION',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ICONID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ISFROZEN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ASPC_CUTOFFHISTORYNAME',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'FACTORYID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CUTOFFMONTH',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'PRODUCTIONLINEID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'OPERATIONID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ASPC_INSPECTIONITEMID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'RESOURCEID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ASPC_QA_CONDITIONID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ASPC_CHARTTYPEID',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'SIGMATYPE',
  'type': 'STRING'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MINOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MAXOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MINOFZBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CLOFR',
  'type': 'FLOAT'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'STDVALUE',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CPKVALUE',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'SIOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'OUTLIEROFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'RUNOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TRENDOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'UCLOFXBAR',
  'type': 'FLOAT'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CLOFXBAR',
  'type': 'FLOAT'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'LCLOFXBAR',
  'type': 'FLOAT'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TOTALPOINTOFXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TOTALOCAPPOINTXBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MAXOFZBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGOFZBAR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MINOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MAXOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'SIOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'OUTLIEROFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'RUNOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TRENDOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'UCLOFR',
  'type': 'FLOAT'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'LCLOFR',
  'type': 'FLOAT'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TOTALPOINTOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TOTALOCAPPOINTOFR',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MINOFS',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MAXOFS',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGOFS',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGVALUE',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'ISDISABLED',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CHGCONTROLLINE',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MINOFW',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MAXOFW',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGOFW',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'APPLYTODATE',
  'type': 'DATE'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'AVGOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'CLOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'LCLOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MAXOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'MINOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'OUTLIEROFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'RUNOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'SIOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TOTALOCAPPOINTOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TOTALPOINTOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'TRENDOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'UCLOFMIN',
  'type': 'INTEGER'},
 {'mode': 'NULLABLE',
  'name': 'NOTES',
  'type': 'STRING'}]
```

Oracle:

```
ASPC_CUTOFFHISTORYID   NOT NULL CHAR(16)       
CDOTYPEID                       NUMBER(10)     
CHANGECOUNT                     NUMBER(10)     
CHANGEHISTORYID                 CHAR(16)       
DESCRIPTION                     VARCHAR2(255)  
ICONID                          NUMBER(10)     
ISFROZEN                        NUMBER(10)     
ASPC_CUTOFFHISTORYNAME          VARCHAR2(50)   
FACTORYID                       CHAR(16)       
CUTOFFMONTH                     VARCHAR2(10)   
PRODUCTIONLINEID                CHAR(16)       
OPERATIONID                     CHAR(16)       
ASPC_INSPECTIONITEMID           CHAR(16)       
RESOURCEID                      CHAR(16)       
ASPC_QA_CONDITIONID             CHAR(16)       
ASPC_CHARTTYPEID                CHAR(16)       
SIGMATYPE                       VARCHAR2(2)    
MINOFXBAR                       NUMBER         
MAXOFXBAR                       NUMBER         
MINOFZBAR                       NUMBER         
CLOFR                           NUMBER         
STDVALUE                        NUMBER         
CPKVALUE                        NUMBER         
AVGOFXBAR                       NUMBER         
SIOFXBAR                        NUMBER         
OUTLIEROFXBAR                   NUMBER         
RUNOFXBAR                       NUMBER         
TRENDOFXBAR                     NUMBER         
UCLOFXBAR                       NUMBER         
CLOFXBAR                        NUMBER         
LCLOFXBAR                       NUMBER         
TOTALPOINTOFXBAR                NUMBER         
TOTALOCAPPOINTXBAR              NUMBER         
MAXOFZBAR                       NUMBER         
AVGOFZBAR                       NUMBER         
MINOFR                          NUMBER         
MAXOFR                          NUMBER         
AVGOFR                          NUMBER         
SIOFR                           NUMBER         
OUTLIEROFR                      NUMBER         
RUNOFR                          NUMBER         
TRENDOFR                        NUMBER         
UCLOFR                          NUMBER         
LCLOFR                          NUMBER         
TOTALPOINTOFR                   NUMBER         
TOTALOCAPPOINTOFR               NUMBER         
MINOFS                          NUMBER         
MAXOFS                          NUMBER         
AVGOFS                          NUMBER         
AVGVALUE                        NUMBER         
ISDISABLED                      NUMBER(10)     
CHGCONTROLLINE                  NUMBER(10)     
MINOFW                          NUMBER         
MAXOFW                          NUMBER         
AVGOFW                          NUMBER         
APPLYTODATE                     DATE           
AVGOFMIN                        NUMBER         
CLOFMIN                         NUMBER         
LCLOFMIN                        NUMBER         
MAXOFMIN                        NUMBER         
MINOFMIN                        NUMBER         
OUTLIEROFMIN                    NUMBER         
RUNOFMIN                        NUMBER         
SIOFMIN                         NUMBER         
TOTALOCAPPOINTOFMIN             NUMBER         
TOTALPOINTOFMIN                 NUMBER         
TRENDOFMIN                      NUMBER         
UCLOFMIN                        NUMBER         
NOTES                           VARCHAR2(2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a DATE field in your BigQuery schema.
I do not know exactly how you are doing this migration but have you tried setting "Use Logical Types" true in your NiFi processor?

EDIT 1.

I replicated your error here and I could solve it by using a schema like this: [ {"mode": "NULLABLE","name": "f0", "type":"STRING"}, {"mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "f1", "type":"INTEGER"}, {"mode": "NULLABLE","name": "f2", "type":"INTEGER"}, {"mode": "NULLABLE","name": "f3", "type":"INTEGER"} ]

Have you tried using double quotes in your schema? Please let me know if it works

Comment: I just tested it after changing the parameter. Still shows the error. As for how my process is setup, I have 'ExecuteSql' for source, 'PutBigQueryBatch' for destination. I have tested the query results to see if there is data and verified its existence. I have also noticed that the Jobs are not created in Bigquery.

Comment: You could also try to set Max Bad Records to 1. Sometimes there is a complete null information in the end of the flowfile.

Comment: I replicated your error here and I could solve it by using a schema like this:

[
{"mode": "NULLABLE","name": "f0", "type":"STRING"},
{"mode": "NULLABLE", "name": "f1", "type":"INTEGER"},
{"mode": "NULLABLE","name": "f2", "type":"INTEGER"},
{"mode": "NULLABLE","name": "f3", "type":"INTEGER"}
]

Have you tried using double quotes in your schema?  
Please let me know if it works

Comment: I replaced all the single quote with double quotes, it still shows the error. I am going to go through the oracle schema and build Bigquery schema manually to see if there is any problem with it.

Comment: You could try also setting the date field as string

Comment: I tried that too, same error. I manually created schema from scratch, the error no longer shows up. Data transfer is complete. I have no idea why it fixed the way it fixed (which is the worst type of fix), but it did.